# VB.NET listbox item switch

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm working on this project where I have IP addresses in a listbox and I've already gotten a method that transfers the listbox items into the textbox , but I need the IPs to change themselves with a button.

For example, I have these three IP addresses:

- 123.456.78
- 891.23.45.6
- 789.123.12

The current IP address in the textbox is 123.456.78 but when I click a button it changes too line two which is 891.23.45.6 and it can ONLY be that in the textbox (not like 123.456.78 is pushed off to the side).

Thats the code I need.

Its all placed under one button , such as -

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    '*Grabbing our proxy text from our online server (this way we can keep updating our proxies).
    Dim Str As System.IO.Stream
    Dim srRead As System.IO.StreamReader
    Try
        ' make a Web request
        Dim req As System.Net.WebRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("https://dl.dropbox.com/somethingOrOther")
        Dim resp As System.Net.WebResponse = req.GetResponse
        Str = resp.GetResponseStream
        srRead = New System.IO.StreamReader(Str)
        ' read all the text 
        TextBox2.Text = srRead.ReadToEnd
    Catch ex As Exception
        TextBox2.Text = "Unable to download content"
    Finally
        '  Close Stream and StreamReader when done
        srRead.Close()
        Str.Close()
    End Try

    ' Assign string to reference.
    Dim value1 As String = TextBox2.Text


    ' Replace word with another word.
    Dim value2 As String = value1.Replace("<br>", vbNewLine)
    TextBox2.Text = value2
    ListBox1.Items.Add(TextBox2.Text)

    '*Now , we're taking our fresh proxies in the textbox and moving them into our listbox.

    ListBox1.Items.AddRange(TextBox2.Text.Split(vbNewLine))
End Sub
```

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Sounds like you need an eventhandler on change

Comment: Can you post some of your code?

Comment: He meant can you post it in your question.

Comment: He also meant "Can you post it in an editable text format, with any sensitive information changed to generic information (like changing the actual dropbox url to something more benign like "https://dl.dropbox.xom/somedropboxurl") instead of a screengrab so you could show us your whole button handler instead of a part of it?" but I suppose I'll take what I can get. :)

Comment: Ah , I just don't have a piece of code that directly relates to that.

Comment: How, on earth, do you get these IP Addresses _891.23.45.6  - 789.123.12_ ?

Comment: -1 : question is poorly asked, and problem seems poorly analysed. (not to mention the code).  What is your intent ? You should be able to state it clearly BEFORE coding it. Do you intent to provide the user with a list of IP, and allow him to ban the selected one with a button ?? Your "IPInfo" Class should have a IsBanned boolean, have a template to show baned items in another color, and maybe disable them also to prevent selection. Then you deal with an observable collection of IPInfo, bound to a ListBox. And you'll be coding in WPF.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [`ListBox.SelectedIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindex.aspx) property.

If you need to check what the value at a particular index is, you can use [`ListBox.Items`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.items.aspx) property.

If you need to iterate through the listbox (for example, to look for a particular value), then you can  make use of the [`ListBox.Items.Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.count.aspx) property:

```
For l_currentIndex As Integer = 0 to MyListBox.Items.Count - 1
    If CStr(MyListBox.Items(l_currentIndex)) = "MyExpectedValue" Then
        MyListBox.SelectedInex = l_currentIndex
        Exit ' Exit For Loop
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
'Assign string to reference.
Dim value1 As String = TextBox2.Text


'Replace word with another word.
Dim value2 As String = value1.Replace("<br>", vbNewLine)
TextBox2.Text = value2
ListBox1.Items.Add(TextBox2.Text)

'*Now , we're taking out fresh proxies in the textbox and moving them into our listbox

ListBox1.Items.AddRange(TextBox2.Text.Split(vbNewLine))
```

is functionally equivalent to this code:

```
TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text.Replace("<br>", vbNewLine)
ListBox1.Items.Add(TextBox2.Text)
ListBox1.Items.AddRange(TextBox2.Text.Split(vbNewLine))
```

The line `ListBox1.Items.AddRange(TextBox2.Text.Split(vbNewLine))` is not going to do what you want because you've already replaced all of the `vbNewLine`s with `<br>` elements (which, by the way, are malformed for XHTML... they should instead be `<br />`...).

If you can post your entire button.click handler, substituting generic information for the sensitive stuff (like your dropbox url), we may be able to assist you better.

**UPDATE:**

Assuming your form markup looks like this:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" SelectionMode="Single" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:ListBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Get Proxies" />
```

Try these for your handlers:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim req As System.Net.WebRequest = Nothing
    Dim resp As System.Net.WebResponse = Nothing
    Dim Str As System.IO.Stream = Nothing
    Dim srRead As System.IO.StreamReader = Nothing
    Dim responseText As String = String.Empty
    Dim proxies() As String = Nothing
    Dim list As ArrayList = Nothing
    Dim ipAddress As String = String.Empty
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    '*Grabbing our proxy text from our online server (this way we can keep updating our proxies).
    Try
        ' make a Web request
        req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("https://dl.dropbox.com/somethingOrOther")
        resp = req.GetResponse
        Str = resp.GetResponseStream
        srRead = New System.IO.StreamReader(Str)
        ' read all the text 
        responseText = srRead.ReadToEnd
    Catch ex As Exception
        responseText = "Unable to download content"
    Finally
        ' Close Stream and StreamReader when done
        srRead.Close()
        Str.Close()
    End Try

    '*Now , we're taking our fresh proxies in the textbox and moving them into our listbox.
    proxies = responseText.Split(vbNewLine)
    For Each ipAddress In proxies
        list.Add(New ListItem(ipAddress))
    Next

    ListBox1.Items.AddRange(list.ToArray(GetType(ListItem)))
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    If ListBox1.SelectedIndex > -1 Then
        TextBox2.Text = ListBox1.SelectedValue
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: but i need it to scroll through the listbox items.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean. The ListBox should already be scrollable (depending on how many items are shown at one time).